# Wikipedia Curie temperature article - confusion about a specific paragraph

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, temperature, nanoscience

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) Curie Temperature page,

> Composite materials , that is, materials composed from
>   other materials with different properties, can change the
>   Curie temperature. For example, a composite which has
>   silver in it can create spaces for oxygen molecules in
>   bonding which decreases the Curie temperature as
>   the crystal lattice will not be as compact.

2 questions:

1. How can silver 'create spaces' for oxygen molecules?
2. I don't understand the use of 'compact'. Does it mean that because of the oxygen molecules in interatomic spaces, silver atoms exchange interaction will become weak, thus, creating disorder in the alignment of magnetic moments (vice-versa for oxygen molecules)?

Or, does it mean because of the inclusion of oxygen molecules in the lattice, the magnetic moment alignment will be disturbed? Or has 2 unpaired electrons which have perpendicular magnetic moments? So, there will be a disorder in the alignment.

Please, share your thoughts.

Comment: Please provide the link to the page, best to the current version via a permalink ya can get directly left from the sidebar, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Page_history#Linking_to_a_specific_version_of_a_page

Comment: I have provided a link. Now, I want an answer.